# Checking empty request uri with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, query-string, http-host

I need to redirect the request from

```
www.mysite.com/?querystring=data
```

to

```
www.mysite.com/dir/phpfile.php/?querystring=data
```

It means that it should be translated only the url with empty request_uri ( for example

```
www.mysite.com/css/style.css
```

should not be translated), and with not empty query string ( for example the main page

```
www.mysite.com/
```

should not be translated).

I wrote this code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ www.mysite.com/$1 [QSA]
```

But it doesn't work. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The rule that you have has the domain name in it without a protocol, it's going to look like a URI or file pathname to mod_rewrite. Additionally, you're rewriting it nothing, since `$1` backreferences the grouping `(.*)` in your match, which *must* be nothing since your condition says the URI can only be `/`. You probably want something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /dir/phpfile.php/ [L,R]
```

The query string will automatically get appended to the end. Remove the `R` if you don't want to externally redirect the browser (thus changing the URL in the location bar), or replace it with `R=301` if you want a permanent redirect.

Comment: I was lazy in defining my needs. Your solution translate also www.mysite.com to www.mysite.com/dir/phpfile.php/. This is not accettable for my site. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /dir/phpfile.php/ [L,QSA,R=302]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.